# How can I call an ASP.Net string function with jQuery AJAX?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have a string function ASP.Net Webform. I want to call this function using AJAX.
That function returns a string value from database with a month index

```csharp
protected string BringDatas(int month)
{

  Counts counts_ = new Counts();
  return counts_.GetMonths(month);
}
```

```js
var dataValue = { "month": 1 };
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Homepage.aspx/BringDatas",
  data: dataValue,
  error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
  },
  complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
    alert("complete: " + status + "\n\nResponse: " + jqXHR.responseText);
  }
});
```

Comment: Note that typing in uppercase is equivalent to shouting and is considered rude. I edited the title for you in this case. With regard to your issue, please provide more context around how you expose the `BringDatas()` method - I would assume that the `protected` modifier is going to be the first problem

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: If you debug, are you actually hitting the WebMethod in the code-behind?  If not, you may try to use this ````'<%= Page.ResolveUrl("Homepage.aspx/OrnekPost") %>'```` as the ````url````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is javascript side

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            $("#Gonder").click(
                function () {
                   
                    $.ajax
                        ({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "Homepage.aspx/OrnekPost",
                            data: "{'parametre':'1234'}",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "text",
                            success: function (output) {
                                alert("Response: "+ output);
                            }, error: function () {
                                alert("hata var");
                            }
                        });
                });
        })
</script>
```

Codebehind.cs code

```
[ScriptMethod]
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static string OrnekPost(string parametre)
        {
            return parametre + " değeriyle post işlemi gerçekleştirildi.";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try:

**Code Behind:**

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string BringDatas(int month)
    {
      Counts counts_ = new Counts();
      return counts_.GetMonths(month);
    }
```

**ajax call**

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'Homepage.aspx/BringDatas',
        data: '{"month": 1}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Response: " + response.d);
        },
        error: function (response) {
        }
    });
```